# Reflections issue with private fields

Tags: java

Вытаскиваю поля из класса А при помощи `getDeclaratedFields()`.

Этот класс наследуется от класса Б.

При этом я не получаю унаследованные поля, помеченные модификатором доступа `private`. Как их достать не изменяя код классов А и Б?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не получаете список, потому что поле декларировано родительским классом. Если вы не можете получить инстанс объекта родительского класса то надо обратиться к полю напрямую по имени и сделать его доступным через `setAccessible()`

```
Field privateField = clazzObject.getDeclaredField("myField");
privateField.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: получилось! Можно всё вытащить из нистанса